# SSIS- seq num genearion based on key in result set

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

Suppose in the OLEDB source query result, I have a result set like this:

```
Account Num   field1 field2 field3 

1
1
2
3
4
```

I want the output to be:

```
Account Num  SEQ NUM   field1 field2 field3
1              1 
1              2 
2              1 
3              1
4              1
```

By which transformation in SSIS can I get this output?

Comment: When you say field you mean columns? Or rows?

Comment: What version of SQL is the data source you are connecting to?

Comment: Don't use a SSIS transfomation. Use the suggestion from @Hadi

Comment: Thanks Hadi and Nick. I used a similar query to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter your oledb source query and use `ROW_NUMBER` function to achieve this:

```
Select [Account Num],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  [Account Num] ORDER BY  [Account Num]) AS  [SEQ Num], 
    Field1, Field2, Field3
  From SourceTable
```